# Find the number $c > 0$ such that the region bounded by the curves $y = x$, $y = -2x$, $x=c$ has area 6.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

My intuition leads me to believe that I need to separate this into two regions and use a definite integral to compute the area. I am having troubles associating $x=c$ and each of the given functions.

Comment: This is my first question on MathSE and am confused by the downvotes. If you would please let know why so I don't continue to make mistakes I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering the below plot, you're obviously called to do the following equation having a definite integral:

$$\int_0^c(x-(-2x))dx=6$$

[image]

Comment: The visual aid helped to establish the correct relation. My confusion was in mixing up x = c and y = c.

Comment: "*Obviously*" is quite a strong word. I'd say that the OP was asked to find the area of a triangle.

Comment: $B.S.Good point, visualisation

Comment: I think there's a big time difference between us I vote  +1 to this nice answer  after 8 hours:-)

Comment: @B.S.: Excellent use of graphics +1

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to integrate.

The lines $y=x$ and $y=-2x$, where $0 \le x \le c$, give the sides of a triangle.

The third side is given by the line joining $(c,c)$ and $(c,-2c)$.

Hence your triangle has base of length $3c$ and height of length $c$.

Use the formula $A=\tfrac{1}{2}\times\text{base}\times\text{height}$ and the fact that $A=6$ to solve for $c$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\;c>0\;$ , then the area is given by

$$\int\limits_0^c\left[x-(-2x)\right]dx=\left.\frac32 x^2\right|_0^c=\frac32c^2=6\iff \ldots$$